# SpecFlow feature file error - Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: specflow

I am getting below error in SpecFlow (2.1.o) in VS 2107 in one of the steps in feature file. Should it be something related to SpecFlow framework issue?

But I don't have this error in other features. They are working fine.

[image]

Error in XXXXfeature.cs file:

```
Test method ABC.Api.Bdd.Tests.Features.V2.InstantTrackerFeature.InstantTrackerReturnsA500ErrorResponseWhenErrorScenariosOccur threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
    at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.StepArgumentTypeConverter.ConvertSimple(Type typeToConvertTo, Object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.StepArgumentTypeConverter.ConvertSimple(IBindingType typeToConvertTo, Object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.StepArgumentTypeConverter.Convert(Object value, IBindingType typeToConvertTo, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ConvertArg(Object value, IBindingType typeToConvertTo)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<GetExecuteArguments>b__0(Object arg, Int32 argIndex)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__5`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.GetExecuteArguments(BindingMatch match)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
   at ABC.Api.Bdd.Tests.Features.V2.InstantTrackerFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
   at ABC.Api.Bdd.Tests.Features.V2.InstantTrackerFeature.InstantTrackerReturnsA500ErrorResponseWhenErrorScenariosOccur() in C:\ABC.API\ABC.Api.Bdd.Tests\features\v2\InstantTracker.feature:line 36
```

Comment: After further investigation, it seems like the issue with whole feature file. None of the scenarios are working because of this same error. Regenerated the feature file, no luck though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error was missing `StepArgumentTransformation`. as below.

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
        public IList<MovesStaging> TransformMovesStaging(Table identifiers)
        {
            return identifiers.Rows.Select(row => new MovesStaging
            {
                PartitionKey = ParseTableRowFieldAsString(row, "PartitionKey"),
                RowKey = ParseTableRowFieldAsString(row, "RowKey"),
                Timestamp = ParseTableRowFieldAsTimeStampUtc(row, "Timestamp"),
                Status = ParseTableRowFieldAsString(row, "Status"),
                ExpiryDate = ParseTableRowFieldAsDateTimeUtc(row, "ExpiryDate")
            }).ToList();
        }
```

Basically whenever you try to insert data through feature file you need to have this. 
I came across similar type of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738675/how-to-transform-spec-flow-table-data-into-different-values) after that. I missed the question perhaps due to the subject.

Comment: You need this, when you have a binding, that takes a IList<MovesStaging> parameter and not a Table parameter.

Comment: Have also a look at the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist namespace: http://specflow.org/documentation/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers/ There are helpers for handling tables.

Comment: Yes you was right it is solution when you have hidden binding